# Is it possible for me to make this RIA IQueryable web service perform like I want?

Tags: c#, silverlight, wcf-ria-services, iqueryable

I'm writing a Silverlight application using WCF RIA to get most of my data. I have a few instances with `AutoCompleteBoxes` where I want a big list of data, but really only need a few fields from the table. I really wanted to create a UserControl that was generic so that I could just set which `Type` I want it currently using.

The `AutoCompleteBox` has a `DomainDataSource` because I wanted an easy way to filter what data it should display (if it's showing Contacts, then I want to pass in a `FilterDescriptor` that says what type of Contacts to show). I'm fairly certain a `DomainDataSource` needs an Iqueryable return in order to function.. This is what I'm trying to do on the server:

```
public IQueryable<CompactData> GetCompactData(string type)
{
    switch (type)
    {
        case "Contact":
            return this.ObjectContext.Contacts.Select(p => new CompactData() { GUID = p.GUID, Field1 = p.FirstName + " " + p.LastName });//.ToList();
        case "Client_Clients":
            return this.ObjectContext.Client_Clients.Select(p => new CompactData() { GUID = p.GUID, Field1 = p.ClientCode, Field2 = p.Name });//.ToList();
        default:
            throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

I like this idea because the `AutoCompleteBox` can be bound to just Field1 and Field2 with me setting what that means here. More importantly, it's really easy to apply a filter with a `FilterDescriptor` instead of having to build an expression tree manually. Unfortunately my client doesn't see the method while it's returning an Iqueryable (If I change it to return a List then it is visible, but then I'm fairly certain I can't use my FilterDescriptors). The issue is my `CompactData` Type, why isn't that type IQueryable?

Comment: If you're going to vote to close my question, I'd appreciate if you'd say why you think it should be closed or how I can improve the question. I'm trying to do something, I have the code I tried but that isn't working, and now I'm asking what I've done wrong and if what I want is even possible. I don't see the issue..

Comment: Why you use this signature? (string type)

Comment: @SeyyedPuyaSoofbaf Why what about it?

Comment: Can you add the definition of you CompactData class?

Comment: My bet would be on CompactData not having a primary key (I know it's not a database entity, but it still needs a primary key attribute - [Key] - on a unique property for RIA Services) - or that the type is otherwise otherwise unfit for being a RIA Services entity.